# Microsoft Graph API - Read and write user's outlook tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am developing an application which can read and write user's outlook tasks. I'm able to read the tasks assigned to my user id with the below API.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/outlook/tasks

When I try to read other user's tasks by providing the userPrincipalName I'm getting 403 error.

Request: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/support@foobar.com/outlook/tasks

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "05fab540-3638-4b61-95ef-f2470539f385",
        "date": "2018-04-07T07:25:06"
    }
}
}
```

I thought it is an application/delegated permission assigned to the application I have registered in Azure portal. But I doubt whether Microsoft allows us to read and write other user's task.

[image: active directory application]

Please let me know whether it is possible to read other user's tasks.

Comment: You can only read a logged in user's task.

Comment: Why don't you use Microsoft Graph explorer and run the query by giving all the required permissions.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Graph API explorer.

Comment: Is the querried user part of the same Group?

Comment: And i just checked that Work and school accounts are only permitted. Personal accounts can't access the data. I am on a mobile device and I can assist once I am on system.

Comment: It is a work account and the user is part of the same tenant.

Comment: Shared Tasks in this context means the Tasks Folders that the UserId has been granted explicit access to (eg those Tasks folder you can access in Outlook or OWA). All the above is doing is granting your App the rights to use the graph's Tasks API endpoint but it doesn't grant the rights to the actual folder in the Mailbox this is still controlled via the Mailbox folder DCAL's

Comment: @GlenScales Can you please be specific what is the access right I have to provide to access other users tasks?

Comment: There are a few way of doing it eg Add-MailboxFolderPermission, Outlook Delegation (eg folder sharing) or even Add-MailboxPermission. As I mentioned if you can access the folder in Outlook with the user you using the it should work fine in REST. Application permissions are the other module you can use for an app that need tenant wide access https://www.eliostruyf.com/building-daemon-or-service-app-with-the-microsoft-graph-api/